# Using Jest for "import * as" mocking

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

Could you please tell how to mock this kind of import using jest ?

`import * as some from 'some-package';`

Comment: If the solution worked, would you please consider accepting the answer? @BonFrero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try mocking like follows

```
jest.mock('some-package', () => ({
 // mock your methods or anything you want here, if not required leave this as is
}))
```

or

```
jest.mock('some-package');
```

Dont forget to use `jest.unmock('some-package');` i you have other usecases